# Nodejs Multer diskStorage not working - why destination targeting temp folder and not uploading

Tags: node.js, multer, keystonejs

I am using Multer to upload a profile image and unfortunately not working correctly. This is my code:

```
var express =   require("express");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var app         =   express();
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('avatar');

exports.uploadAvatar = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

and the route:

```
app.post('/api/uploadAvatar', requiredAuthentication, routes.api.instructor.uploadAvatar);
```

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" id="editProfile" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/uploadAvatar">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Profile image <span>*</span></label>
        <input type="file" name="avatar" class="form-control" id="avatar" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="button" id="btnSubmit">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is what the `console.log(req.files);` is logging:
[image]

As you can see, destination is targetting the 'Temp' folder and the filename is not generated. Can someone please find out where things going wrong here?

Please note that I'm using a keystoneJS framework but I beleive it shoudn't make any impact on this.

Comment: What versions of KeystoneJS and Multer are you using?

Comment: @Stennie
KeystoneJS - 4, NodeJS - 10.5, Multer - 1.3

Answer (score 8):

Just the same problem (REST-API, Node.js, Postman, POST request, Upload Image, multer):

("multer": "^1.4.2")

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './upload');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        return cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});
```

**But this works:**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './upload',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        return cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
var express =   require("express");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var app         =   express();
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('avatar');

module.exports. = { uploadAvatar: upload };
```

This may works.

Comment: Thanks but this is not helping my issue. Now I'm starting think that KeystoneJS is overriding something

Answer (score 0):

In my all node API, I have used `multer` this way and all time it works fine for me.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    console.log(file)
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
  }
})
```

For more details please look inti this [Link](https://evdokimovm.github.io/javascript/nodejs/expressjs/multer/2016/11/03/Upload-files-to-server-using-NodeJS-and-Multer-package-filter-upload-files-by-extension.html).

Hope it may also help you.

Comment: Thanks but this is not helping my issue. Now I'm starting think that KeystoneJS is overriding something

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the folder structure of your app but it seems the path you're choosing is targeting the parent of the public folder. You can copy the relative path of the public folder and add on the other folders or I think doing /public/whatever might help you

Also to reference the image, you have to call it from your public file if it's your static folder.
So 
The src path is from the static folder so u needn't add that