# Node js Multer file upload with extra text input fields

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to upload a file to disk using multer. Here is my code:

```
 const multer  = require('multer');


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, __basedir + '/uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname)
    }
});


var upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

And here goes my form to collect the file and some extra input fields

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/uploadfile">
<input name="cate" type="hidden" value="<%= category %>" id="cate" name="cate"></input>
<br>
<input type="file" name="uploadfile"  class="btn-success" value="Select Source">
        <input  type="submit" class="btn-success"  ><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a new Source</input>
```

This function uploads **public/img/bg.jpg** to my database, thou i would like the file to be picked by the user. How can i get the filepath string in req.files object

```
fs.createReadStream('public/img/bg.jpg')
  .pipe(fileUpload.createWriteStream())
  .on('error', function(err) {
console.log("fail");})
  .on('finish', function() {
    console.log("success");
  });
  });
```

Comment: just console your re.body and see what are you getting in that object and acces the values from req.body object . cant see any text field here..if you have any just access it by **req.body.yourTextFieldName**.

Comment: ok lets assume the user picked a file from the html form above, how would i get the file path so that i pass it to the fs.createReadStream() function? and also the req.body.yourTextFieldName doesnt work.is it because the input is type hidden?

Comment: Your using `express-fileupload` or `multer` ?

Comment: First part of code show your using `multer` and last part show your using `express-fileupload`

Comment: please go through this resembles to your query [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110048/multer-file-filename-and-file-path-undefined ] if link dont work copy and paste

Comment: @Shubham Tiwari when i console.log(req.file) i get undefined. but when i console.log(req.files)  { avatar: 
   { name: 'Mobile Application.doc',
     data: <Buffer d0 cf 11 e0 a1 b1 1a e1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3e 00 03 00 fe ff 09 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 ... >,
     encoding: '7bit',
     tempFilePath: undefined,
     truncated: false,
     mimetype: 'application/msword',
     md5: [Function: md5],
     mv: [Function: mv] } }

Comment: am looking for a variable with the path to the selected file.or its destination

Comment: check this one implement accoding to it [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206055/nodejs-multer-diskstorage-not-working-why-destination-targeting-temp-folder-an ]